# RuntimeError at /accounts/register/ There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'

Tags: python, django

I want to implement an email verification in my django app so, I am using an external module verify_email in that there is a function called verify_email() to check whether an entered email address exists or not. In my view.py file I am checking if the mail is valid then a user is created but, the problem is the function verify_email() takes some time to get the result. I think we need to use some kind of await statement to wait for the result but I am getting errors like this when I try to use it normally.

[This](https://pypi.org/project/verify-email/) is the pypi project link.

```py
def register(request):
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['pass']
        username = request.POST['username']
        check = verify_email(email)
        
        if check:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
            user.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'email invalid')
            return redirect('register')
```

Description of the error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/

Django Version: 3.2.3
Python Version: 3.8.5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akshith/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/akshith/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/akshith/Desktop/django-app/testing/final (copy)/accounts/views.py", line 55, in register
    check = verify_email(email)
  File "/home/akshith/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/verify_email/verify_email.py", line 103, in verify_email
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'

Exception Type: RuntimeError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

Is there a way to use asyncio or any other ways to deal with this kind of error?

Comment: `verify_email` normally should not take that much time. With a proper database index, etc. this should run in milliseconds.

Comment: True But, still I am getting this error. I thought error is because of verify_email() because if I remove that part everything works fine.

Comment: well then the problem is located there, so It might be better to share the details of the `verify_email` function (and all related functions).

Comment: @Willem the `verify_email` is from a third party application the OP has linked above, it seems to check that if an email actually exists so the time taken might perhaps actually be valid (making a request to the email domain, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really think that the user should proceed even without email verification ?
It usually takes atleast few seconds to verify email on any website, So that should not be a problem. And for Concurrent requests you don't need to worry because django handles them very efficiently.

And sorry, I didn't had enough reputation to comment :)

Comment: Do you mean without email OTP verification?


And, No issue for not commenting.

Comment: Not OTP verification, Only Email validation. Suppose you add asynchronous code here and if a user enters an invalid email. The view will redirect them to the next page. and then it finds out the email was invalid and then redirects again to signin page with the error. isn't it painful  :(

Comment: Fortunately, My aim is also same and What I am doing in the code is checking if mail is valid, if so creating the account else I am redirecting the user to the same page with a message ```messages.info(request,'email invalid')```.